# resizing a BUTTON through CSS

Tags: button, resize, jquery-mobile

I use jquery mobile to generate my buttons and I have a CSS code below to change its design but no matter what value i put in width and height the size of the button doesn't change, but it is relatively dependent on the font size of the label. How can I change this so I can change the button size irregardless of the font size of the label?

```
$("#ui-1").css({'position':'absolute','left':'27.0px','top':'51.0px','width':'120.0px','height':'30.0px',});
$("#ui-1 .ui-btn-text").css({'font-family':'"Calibri","Arial","Sans Serif"','font-size':'0.75em','color':'black','text-align':'left','wordwrap':'normal','text-shadow':'1px 1px 1px #FFFFFF'});
```

Comment: You can put those styles in a stylesheet.

Comment: does that make make a difference? i tried it but the result is the same

Comment: They should have the same result, but I find stylesheets to be much more readable. Just personal preference (and it'll help the people with JS turned off).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Live Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/3EgrW/21/ (Width)
- http://jsfiddle.net/3EgrW/35/ (Height)

JS:

```
// For all buttons use something like this
$('.ui-btn').css('width','50%');

// For individual buttons use something like this
$('#theButton1').parent().css('width', '75%');

// Or this for HREF data-role buttons
$('#hrefButton4').css('width', '45%');
```

UPDATE: (I think this is what you're looking for)

```
// this changes the height for all buttons
$('.ui-btn-text').css('font-size','50px');

// This changes the height for a single element 
$('#hrefButton3').children().children().css('font-size','30px');
```

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home"> 
    <div data-role="content">
        <input type="button" id="theButton1" value="Press Me 1" />
        <input type="button" id="theButton2" value="Press Me 2" />
        <input type="button" id="theButton3" value="Press Me 3" />
        <input type="button" id="theButton4" value="Press Me 4" />
        <br />
        <a href="#" data-role="button" id="hrefButton1">HREF Me 1</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" id="hrefButton2">HREF Me 2</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" id="hrefButton3">HREF Me 3</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" id="hrefButton4">HREF Me 4</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi phill! thank you very much for your help! will try this! one more thing... I needed also to adjust their width but it seems like its not working

Comment: oh im sorry, i meant the height. the example can adjust the width but when i try to add the height and adjust it it doesnt update the height

Comment: I've added another example link and updated my answer as well for height

Comment: hi phil im back again. just wanna ask, i am being troubled by the vertical scrollbars shown in your example and it shows on my application. do you have any idea how can i eliminate it? and also can you explain to me why $('#theButton1').parent().css('width', '75%') needs to access the parent first? thanks so much

Comment: Can I have a link to your application? hard to debug what's going on from a question. as for accessing the parent element, jQM adds a layer of html and css to get the desired effect, look and feel and functionality. If you use Chrome of FF and view the site you can use the debugger to see all the added code and work your way from there.

Comment: ahm thanks for your help. apparently the .height() is now magically supported in the latest RC of the jQueryMobile. I guess that was a bug on the beta versions. now if i run my orig code on the RC 1 it runs as I wanted it to be. again thanks man for your nonstop support!

Answer (score 1):

Made a small test for you, maybe it will help to start you off

http://jsfiddle.net/3EgrW/1/

just a input button and a little css

**Updated**

Added a example with JQuery 1.6.2 working fine aswell

http://jsfiddle.net/3EgrW/2/

Comment: hi benjamin! this is working... but my problem is i need to use jquerymobile to apply the look and feel of the button UI. when I apply jquerymobile css and javascript it seems like it doesnt override the css

Answer (score 0):

The button *might* be an `inline` element. Make it an `inline-block`:

```
display: inline-block;
```