# jQuery Mobile Element Sizes

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, webview

Thou it is simple, I have searched this around the internet and I couldn't come up with a solution.  I believe the solution must be something very simple, but anyways, here's the problem.

I made a mobile web with jQueryMobile (webView for a native app indeed), and everything seems to be so big.  I tried that I can use style="width:xx" to set the button width, but what about the height?  The overall sizes in general.

Like, the  header is filling up a quarter of my page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Live Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/3EgrW/21/ (Width)
- http://jsfiddle.net/3EgrW/35/ (Height)

JS:

```
// For all buttons use something like this
$('.ui-btn').css('width','50%');

// For individual buttons use something like this
$('#theButton1').parent().css('width', '75%');

// Or this for HREF data-role buttons
$('#hrefButton4').css('width', '45%');
```

UPDATE: (I think this is what you're looking for)

```
// this changes the height for all buttons
$('.ui-btn-text').css('font-size','50px');

// This changes the height for a single element 
$('#hrefButton3').children().children().css('font-size','30px');
```

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home"> 
    <div data-role="content">
        <input type="button" id="theButton1" value="Press Me 1" />
        <input type="button" id="theButton2" value="Press Me 2" />
        <input type="button" id="theButton3" value="Press Me 3" />
        <input type="button" id="theButton4" value="Press Me 4" />
        <br />
        <a href="#" data-role="button" id="hrefButton1">HREF Me 1</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" id="hrefButton2">HREF Me 2</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" id="hrefButton3">HREF Me 3</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" id="hrefButton4">HREF Me 4</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Related:

- [resizing a BUTTON through CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303035/resizing-a-button-through-css/7308540#7308540)

Comment: thanks. I actually saw that answer in the original post.  I thought there would be a more simple way to do it. But thanks, that helps.

Comment: jQM adds a lot of extra HTML to give it the look and feel across multiple devices, IMHO it's best to use something like Chrome dev tools or Firebug and view the added HTML elements, find the ones needed to manipulate this way.