# dynamically change the size of text in button jquerymobile

Tags: button, text, jquery-mobile

I have the following piece of code that generate a jquerymobile-style button

```
<a href="#" data-role="button"  
        data-theme="b" id="svbutton" style="position: absolute; top: 30%; margin-left: 0%;margin-right: 0%;  width: 80%; height: 20%; text-align: center;  font-size: 2.50em">Load Time...</a>
```

It is true that when the screen get re-scaled, the size of the button will change. However the size of the text does not change. Is there a way to change the size according to the size of the device-screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read the document's width, or the button's, and then make the font-size of the button relative to that width, eg.:

```
var buttonWidth = $('#svbutton').width();
var fontSize = buttonWidth / 10;
$('#svbutton').css('font-size', fontSize + 'px');
```

**JSFiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/VFube/1

Answer (score 0):

Live Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/Pjvvx/ (Width)
- http://jsfiddle.net/3DSGT/ (Height)

JS:

```
// For all buttons use something like this
$('.ui-btn').css('width','50%');

// For individual buttons use something like this
$('#theButton1').parent().css('width', '75%');

// Or this for HREF data-role buttons
$('#hrefButton4').css('width', '45%');
```

I think this is what you're looking for

```
// this changes the height for all buttons
$('.ui-btn-text').css('font-size','50px');

// This changes the height for a single element 
$('#hrefButton3').children().children().css('font-size','30px');
```

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home"> 
    <div data-role="content">
        <input type="button" id="theButton1" value="Press Me 1" />
        <input type="button" id="theButton2" value="Press Me 2" />
        <input type="button" id="theButton3" value="Press Me 3" />
        <input type="button" id="theButton4" value="Press Me 4" />
        <br />
        <a href="#" data-role="button" id="hrefButton1">HREF Me 1</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" id="hrefButton2">HREF Me 2</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" id="hrefButton3">HREF Me 3</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" id="hrefButton4">HREF Me 4</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Related:

- [resizing a BUTTON through CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303035/resizing-a-button-through-css)