# JQUERY CSS how to modify

Tags: jquery, css

Phill Pafford mentioned this code:

[resizing a BUTTON through CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303035/resizing-a-button-through-css)

and this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/3DSGT/

JS:

```
// For all buttons use something like this
$('.ui-btn').css('width','50%');

// For individual buttons use something like this
$('#theButton1').parent().css('width', '75%');

// Or this for HREF data-role buttons
$('#hrefButton4').css('width', '45%');

// this changes the height for all buttons
$('.ui-btn-text').css('font-size','50px');

// This changes the height for a single element 
$('#hrefButton3').children().children().css('font-size','30px');
```

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home"> 
    <div data-role="content">
        <input type="button" id="theButton1" value="Press Me 1" />
        <input type="button" id="theButton2" value="Press Me 2" />
        <input type="button" id="theButton3" value="Press Me 3" />
        <input type="button" id="theButton4" value="Press Me 4" />
        <br />
        <a href="#" data-role="button" id="hrefButton1">HREF Me 1</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" id="hrefButton2">HREF Me 2</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" id="hrefButton3">HREF Me 3</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" id="hrefButton4">HREF Me 4</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried this but it does not work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <h<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">      


// WIDTH
// For all buttons use something like this
$('.ui-btn').css('width','100%');

// For individual buttons use something like this
$('#theButton1').parent().css('width', '75%');

// Or this for HREF data-role buttons
$('#hrefButton4').css('width', '45%');

// Height of the button
//$('.ui-btn-inner').css('height','50px'); // this changes all buttons, might also need to adjust the vertical alignment for the text as well
$('#theButton2').prev().css('height','50px');

// Height of the font in the button
//$('.ui-btn-text').css('font-size','50px'); // this changes all buttons
$('#hrefButton3').children().children().css('font-size','60px');
​​​
    </script> 



  </head>
  <body>
    <div data-role="page" id="home"> 
    <div data-role="content">
        <input type="button" id="theButton1" value="Press Me 1" />
        <input type="button" id="theButton2" value="Press Me 2" />
        <input type="button" id="theButton3" value="Press Me 3" />
        <input type="button" id="theButton4" value="Press Me 4" />
        <br />
        <a href="#" data-role="button" id="hrefButton1">HREF Me 1</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" id="hrefButton2">HREF Me 2</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" id="hrefButton3">HREF Me 3</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" id="hrefButton4">HREF Me 4</a>
   </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

What should I do to make it work? In my case al the text remain the same and not like
in the image.

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: I fail to see `#hrefButton3`'s children and grandchildren in your html source: `$('#hrefButton3').children().children()`

Comment: I just copy and pasted this example from this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/3DSGT/ It's working fine in this example

Answer (score 2):

You are running your script too early.

Do this:

```
$(function()
{
    // WIDTH
    // For all buttons use something like this
    $('.ui-btn').css('width','100%');

    // For individual buttons use something like this
    $('#theButton1').parent().css('width', '75%');

    // Or this for HREF data-role buttons
    $('#hrefButton4').css('width', '45%');

    // Height of the button
    //$('.ui-btn-inner').css('height','50px'); // this changes all buttons, might also need to adjust the vertical alignment for the text as well
    $('#theButton2').prev().css('height','50px');

    // Height of the font in the button
    //$('.ui-btn-text').css('font-size','50px'); // this changes all buttons
    $('#hrefButton3').children().children().css('font-size','60px');
});
```

Comment: Thanks flem. I added $(function() { before and }); after the existing code but no change in the outcome.

Comment: Do I need to add: $(document).ready(function() instead of $(function() because I tried both and no change.

Comment: I have tried the following: js and html in the head, js and html in the body. js in the head while html in the body, html in the head while js in the body, the js with $(document).ready(function() and $(function() none of these comibinations give the desired result. any tips?

Comment: @Timo11 $(function() is the shorthand for $(document).ready()

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">      
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.ui-btn-text').css('font-size','50px')
        $('.ui-btn-inner').css('height','200px');
        });
</script> 
        <a data-corners="false" href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="delete"
          data-iconpos="top" data-theme="a">LIVINGROOM</a> </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```